# Ant logger level ignored in Eclipse ONLY when "Run in the same JRE as the workspace"

Tags: eclipse, ant

This is my first post here so wish me luck.

I'm having a problem where my Log4J logger levels do not get written to the console when running my Ant build file from within Eclipse.

I am only seeing "info" and higher even though I have specified "debug" in the log4j.properties.  I know it is finding my log4j.properties because Ant complains when I temporarily delete the log4j.properties and run the Ant build.

By contrast, I am able to see the correct logging (debug vs info) when I run the Ant build from the command line.  I can even get it to display in Eclipse if I edit the ant file configuration and choose "Separate JRE".  However, I would prefer to "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" (unless anyone argues against it).

I'll gladly respond with any additional requested details if requested.  For now, I'll add some details about my environment:

Windows XP

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Helios SR 2 (v. 3.6.2)

Ant v1.8.2

Java JDK 1.6.0_24

As noted, I can get the debug logging levels to display in Eclipse if i choose "Separate JRE" which is the exact same 1.6.0_24 only now not running within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

To run an ant script inside eclipse with specific commandline parameters, f.e. your log4j listener =

- focus on your ant script in workspace
- context menu use '2 Run as Ant Build'
- in the Edit Configuration dialog choose 'Main' tab
- set your command line parameters in 'Arguments' textfield =

-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener    etc. ..

also see [Ant Manual Listeners and Loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In an effort to narrow down the problem, I created a simple HelloWorld class with log4j statements for debug, info, warn and tested running it in ant in Eclipse using the "Run in the same JRE as the workspace".

The simple test works fine.  So now I'm back to looking at my more complex example where I am experiencing the problem.  The problem code is using the org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask in ant and eclipse.  It's logger statements are not being generated in Eclipse but get printed fine when running ant from the command line or via Eclipse and separate JRE.

Comment: So bottom line is that log4j is working in Eclipse with Ant, just not working in the specific situation where i run HibernateToolTask ant task in Eclipse (works fine from command line).

Comment: OK, so you're question is answered ;-) Never worked with Hibernate, but IMO the remaining problem is only a configuration problem with your hibernate task, eclipse doesn't know of your hibernate-log4j.properties configfile. Note there's also a Hibernate Plugin for Eclipse => http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html . Logging is also mentioned in the documentation => http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#debug_log